# Is it possible to remove certain files types from certain folders using wild cards. within a command prompt / batch file

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, wildcards

I have a files I need to remove within a certain file structure from a certain directory but have multiple directories but within the structure there is a defining folder.

e:\archive\ *\3 WIP\ *...\ *.fem

the \ *\   -  I need a wild card as I have many

the \ *...\   -  I need a wild card for multiple folders depths ( *\ *\ *\ *\ *.fem) in which I need any *.fem files deleting.

The \3 WIP\ is the defining directory.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but unfortunately I can't show how off the top of my head.

Comment: Cheers Dog Lover at least while I am looking how to do it. It may at least be possible. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Either go to the root of E: and simply run:

DEL /Q *.fem /s

or:
DEL /Q E:\archive\3 WIP\*.fem /s

Note: The /s is key as it traverses all of the subfolders under it.

Just run: DEL /? for help in how to use it.

if you don't want to do this from a command-line, search out *.fem from Windows Explorer and delete from there.

Comment: Cheers Leptonator, I am aware of above but my file structures are many and I have variable folders after archive and before 3 WIP ( archive / * / 3 WIP/ its that one that's causing me trouble, I'm presuming it will have to be in a batch file and be a multi line command. There are more than a couple hundred of these file structures in total :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this whith Powershell.
There is the `get-childitem` cmdlet. Something like `get-childitem e:\archive -include *.fem -recurse` should give you a list with all `*.fem` files in `e:\archive`.
You could then pipe this to a cmdlet to remove the files:

`get-childitem e:\archive -include *.fem -recurse| foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}`

Comment: Cheers duenni I looked at this command but was unsuccessful, is it because I need a Wildcard after the archive but then I need 3 WIP so e: \archive \ * \ 3 WIP \

Comment: "-Path" param (implied here) can take wildcards so could actually do: get-childitem e:\archive\\*.fem..."